# EF Core 3.0 Linq could not be translated for sub-collection

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.0

I am aware of the breaking changes from EF Core 2.2 to EF Core 3.0, but the following query doesn't seem complex to me as it is a simple join in SQL.

I have a list of recipients I need to send an email to. These recipients are grouped and I can add a list of groups to an email alert.

What is wrong with this query?

```cs
var emailAlert = new EmailAlert();

var emailRecipientMailboxes = _emailRecipientRepository
  .Where(x => x.GroupedRecipients.Any(erg => emailAlert.RecipientGroups
  .Any(aerg => aerg.RecipientGroupId == erg.RecipientGroupId)))
  .ToList() // Added so EFCore translates this on the client
  .Select(x => new MailboxAddress(x.FullName, x.Email))
  .ToList();
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<GroupedRecipient>
    .Where(g => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>((EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: Recipient
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
        IsNullable: False
    ), "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>((EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: Recipient
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
        IsNullable: False
    ), "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(g, "RecipientId"))
    .Any(g => __alert_RecipientGroups_0
        .Any(aerg => aerg.RecipientGroupId == g.RecipientGroupId))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

On a side note, is there anywhere I can find out how to translate queries in to ones that will work for EFCore 3.0? Maybe some kind of guide that outlines what types of queries don't work and an example of how to fix them?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error, and possibly some of the relevant stack trace?

Comment: Added above, thanks :)

Comment: how you think `emailAlert.RecipientGroups` would be translated to SQL when `emailAlert` is client side variable?

Comment: You pass an initialized object which LINQ cannot translate to a query. 
Your problem is the emailAlert.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks guys! Is there any rules or a guide I can follow that make it easier to spot these mistakes?

Comment: @oli_taz honestly no. You have to think in a db kind of way. Think what LINQ cannot translate, usually it makes sense, and of course runtime errors :). Of course you can make your query work like you have it above. If you added a ToList() before which sends the query then all are objects so you can do whatever you want basically and are in memory of course.